# Printing triangles using nested loop in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to print a certain triangle in Java by using Nested Loops and I am having difficulty. Could somebody give me a hand or just show me how it's done?

The triangle is:

```
   123456654321
   1234554321
   12344321
   123321
   1221
   11
```

I can print a triangle like

```
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

Though I'm not sure how to reverse and make my loops count down afterwards.

Comment: You wrote `124...` in your first line, and in your third line you have `...3221`. Are those typos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 6;
        while (n > 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
            for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
            System.out.println("");
            n--;
        }
    }
}
```

The second `for` loop assigns `n` to the iterator `int i`, executes the statements within the curly brackets, then decrements `i` using `i--` until the condition `i > 0` is no longer true.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I'll try this out! :)

Comment: Would you mind explaining this to me? I see how it works but I just don't understand how to initiate that it begins to count down?

Comment: Nevermind I see how it works now. Thank you once again for helping with this.

Also, I should note that I had to remove the package com.company in order for this to work. I have only used standard Java packages until now and I'm not sure if I have the proper program or setup to use it. It was still functional, though. I use Jetbrains IntelliJ Idea